# How would one make an array (list or dict) of this class object?

Tags: python

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends

Sometimes it is useful to have a data type similar to the Pascal “record” or C “struct”, bundling together a few named data items. An empty class definition will do nicely:

```
class Employee:
    pass
john = Employee()  # Create an empty employee record
# Fill the fields of the record
john.name = 'John Doe'
john.dept = 'computer lab'
john.salary = 1000
```

I find this method of storing data very useful, I am a vb.Net guy learning python, in vb I would just go

```
Dim x(Mydata.getupperbound(0)) as Employee


and populate it like 
For i as integer = 0 to Mydata.getupperbound(0)
  x(i).name = mydata(i).Name
  x(i).dept = mydata(i).dept
  x(i).salary = mydata(i).salary

next
```

Question: Would like to do similar action in python, using a python class like a .Net structure? HOw can this be done.

Thanks

Comment: what is the format of mydata in python? ie dict, csv, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this in python is by creating a class which has the required attributes.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, dept, salary="100K"):
        self.name = name
        self.dept = dept
        self.salary = salary

emp1 = Employee("Mark", "Sales", "150K")
emp2 = Employee("John", "Engineering")   # Salary is set to default value of 100K
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do full data abstraction and store data inside a object, then make the name, dept, salary of type list and make a sep function to add the values together inside the list together

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = []
        self.department = []
        self.salary = []

    def add_data(self, name, dept, salary):
        self.name.append(name)
        self.salary.append(salary)
        self.department.append(dept)


names =['a', 'b', 'c']
depts =['x', 'y', 'z']
salary = [100,200,3000]

x = Employee()

for name, dept, sal in zip(names, depts, salary):
    x.add_data(name, dept, sal)

for name, dept, sal in zip(x.name, x.department, x.salary):
    print(name, dept, sal, sep='\t')
```

output

```
a   x   100
b   y   200
c   z   3000
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question title correctly, you have the Employee class, instantiated as john in the first listing and want to turn it into a dict or list? Every class already has a `__dict__` attribute that you can access:

```
>>> class Employee:
...     pass
...
>>> john = Employee()
>>> john.name = 'John Doe'
>>> john.dept = 'computer lab'
>>> john.salary = 1000
>>>
>>> john.__dict__
{'name': 'John Doe', 'dept': 'computer lab', 'salary': 1000}
>>> john.__dict__['name']
'John Doe'
```

You can then turn john into a dict directly:

```
>>> john = john.__dict__
>>> john['name']
'John Doe'
```

See also: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3.7+, [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) fill your use case perfectly:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Employee:
    name: str
    dept: str
    # Could also be float if that fits better
    # These are just annotations and do not actually control the held data type
    salary: int
```

Instantiating them is simple:

```
john = Employee('John Doe', 'computers', 1000)
bill = Employee('Billy Joe', 'marketing', 900)
```

And the `dataclasses` module auto-implements nice printing of the instances as well:

```
>>>print(john)
Employee(name='John Doe', dept='computers', salary=1000)
>>>print(bill)
Employee(name='Billy Joe', dept='marketing', salary=900)
```

Comment: The @dataclass looks great, thanks, so I can populate it with a FOR or WHILE loop piece of cake. Thanks